# How to put a delay on swiper.js slides in vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I use swiper.js 10.3 and i can't put delay on my slides :(

Here is my code, I set autoplay to true so that my slides change automatically (which works very well) :

```
<swiper-container
        v-if="!UnvalidUrl && Maindata.slides && Maindata.slides[0]"
        class="home__slider__swiper swiper-container"
        :slides-per-view="1"
        :pagination="true"
        :speed="700"
        :loop="true"
        :navigation="true"
        :autoplay="true"
        :initial-slide="initialSlide"
        @slidechange="emitSlide"
      >
```

However when I try to add delay in autoplay it doesn't work. Here are some tests I tried to get it working without success :

`:autoplay="5000"`
`:autoplay="{ delay: 5000 }"`

For this version of swiper.js I can't find the doc that would allow me to do that :(
If anyone could help me that would be really great!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your second attempt is the correct one but you might need to include the corresponding CSS styles - `swiper/css/autoplay.css`